# SAML configuration of Keycloak in Wildfly 9

Tags: wildfly, saml, keycloak

Securing appl with Keycloak v1.7 and dont want modify me war. Keycloak GUI generates for me client a Wildfly subsystem XML with i put into standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:keycloak-saml:1.1">
        <secure-deployment name="me war name.war">
            <realm>me_realm_name</realm>
            <realm-public-key>me_key</realm-public-key>
            <auth-server-url>me_url</auth-server-url>
            <bearer-only>true</bearer-only>
            <ssl-required>EXTERNAL</ssl-required>
            <resource>some_name</resource>
        </secure-deployment>
    </subsystem>
```

But such cunfiguration can be parsed (WFLYCTL0198: Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:domain:keycloak-saml:1.1}realm' encountered)
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Or is the "Wildfly subsystem XML" in GUI for other purpose and i must define all the SP etc. mentioned in http://keycloak.github.io/docs/userguide/saml-client-adapter/html/jboss-adapter.html#d4e277

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, its is not about SAML. Its configuration just for keycloak. More: https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/topics/jboss-adapter.html